# Kilo Formatter with Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started learning TypeScript with newbie examples.

I want create a pipe for converting `int` to kilo. As example `if input = 1234 return 1.2K`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'kiloFormater' })
export class KiloFormaterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(num: number): string {
        if (num >= 1000000000)
            return (num / 1000000000).toString() + 'B';

        if (num >= 1000000)
            return (num / 1000000).toString() + 'M';

        if (num >= 1000)
            return (num / 1000).toString() + 'K';

        return num.toString(); 
    }
}
```

**Edit**
This code returns 1K, but I want to know how can I get 1.2K.

I can do that in C# with an extension

```
public static string FormatNumber(this long num)
{
    if (num >= 100000000) {
        return (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.#M");
    }
    if (num >= 1000000) {
        return (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.##M");
    }
    if (num >= 100000) {
        return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.#k");
    }
    if (num >= 10000) {
        return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.##k");
    }

    return num.ToString("#,0");
}
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my code returns 1K. I want to see 1.2K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toFixed(n)` for turning a number into a string with an arbitrary precision of `n` decimal places.

```js
function transform (value) {
  if (value >= 1e6) return (value / 1e6).toFixed(1) + 'M'
  if (value >= 1e3) return (value / 1e3).toFixed(1) + 'K'
  return value.toString()
}

console.log(transform(1234))
console.log(transform(1234567))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lazar Ljubenović:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'kiloFormater' })
export class KiloFormaterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): string {
        if (value >= 1e9) return (value / 1e9).toFixed(1) + 'B'
        if (value >= 1e6) return (value / 1e6).toFixed(1) + 'M'
        if (value >= 1e3) return (value / 1e3).toFixed(1) + 'K'
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```